# How to access a src video from an iframe #document?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

I am writing because I am scraping the jkanime page, my intention is to get the mp4 link but it is inside an iframe #document. I try to access using cheerio but it shows me undefined.

Any help will be appreciated

Here I leave the image of the source code where I want to get the link from mp4.

[jkanime web site source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOsDw.jpg)

**Code**

```js
  const getAnimeContent = (id , chapter) =>{
    return fetch(`${url}${id}/${chapter}/`)
     .then(res => res.text())
       .then((body) =>{
        const $ = cheerio.load(body);
        const video = $("video source").attr('src')
        console.log(video);
        return {}
     })
  }
```

Comment: Is url the page url or the iframe src? It needs to be the iframe src

Comment: Hi @pguardiario ,

I found a way to get the mp4 src, but from the devtool.
But I do not know how to apply it with cheerio.

document.querySelector("iframe.player_conte").contentDocument.body.querySelector ("source").src

Answer (score 0):

First you get the iframe src:

```
let iFrameSrc = $("iframe").attr('src')
```

Then you fetch that and load cheerio again.

Comment: It only makes reference to the src of facebook like.php and not to the iframe that has the content of the videos